# How can I inject a Store to another Store in mobX

Tags: javascript, meteor, store, mobx, mobx-react

I am using mobX in combination with React and Meteor and I need to be able to use information saved in one Store in another. Specifically, I need to have a reference of Store A in Store B in order to call an action of Store A and get the information that it had retrieved by subscribing to a collection. I used the @inject decorator but do not know how to call the action. Thank you

Comment: [Update:] I found out an efficient solution from point of view of the general architecture: it is better to have a root store which makes the access of different stores to the data possible. The necessity of different components of an application of having access to the same data is very common, in order to avoid redundancy, it is possible to split the architecture on two levels.

Answer (score 7):

`@inject` is used to inject something from the `Provider` into a React component, not between stores.

You could just import the first store into the second store and call the action straight away.

**Example**

```
// store1.js
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

class Store1 {
  @observable count = 0;

  @action increment() {
    ++this.count;
  }
}

export default new Store1();

// store2.js
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';
import store1 from './store1';

class Store2 {
  @observable name = 'foobar';

  constructor() {
    store1.increment();
  }

  @action changeName(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

export default new Store2();
```

Comment: I don't understand why everyone's suggesting to rely on module cache as a data storage (exporting class instance and then importing it). This can be broken very easy.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it via following steps

```
// store1.js
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

class Store1 {
  @observable count = 0;

  @action increment() {
    ++this.count;
  }
}

export default new Store1();

// store2.js
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';
import store1 from './store1';
const store = new store1()

class Store2 {
  @observable name = 'foobar';

  @action changeName(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

@action
increment(){
 store.increment();
}
}

export default new Store2();
```